# Create multiple routes and nested routes from array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have an array of items, each item needs to have its own route and some other nested routes.
Think of it like this:

- myapp.com/[item] (main item page)
- myapp.com/[item]/about (about item page)
- myapp.com/[item]/faq (faq item page)

The thing is I have a list of items and each one should ideally have their own `about` and `faq` pages. It would be nice if I could be able to just iterate over an array and have each Route rendered. Something like this:

```js
const items = [
  { id: 1, name: 'item1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'item2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'item3' },
  { id: 4, name: 'item4' }
]

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        {items.map(({ id, name }, index) => (
          <React.Fragment key={id}>
            <Route path={`/${name}`} component={<ItemComponent />} />
            <Route path={`/${name}/about`} component={<AboutItemComponent />} />
            <Route path={`/${name}/faq`} component={<FaqItemComponent />} />
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
        <Route path="*" render={() => <div>Not Found</div>} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

This unfortunately does not work. Following issue occur:

- Only the first item actually gets a route. The others render nothing (no 404s or anything, but I get a blank page).
- If I try to access the nested routes, I get 404s, even for the one route that actually renders.

If I am only going through the array to render a single route, they work fine. I am referring to something like this:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        {items.map(({ id, name }, index) => (
          <Route path={`/${name}`} component={<ItemComponent />} />
        ))}
        <Route path="*" render={() => <div>Not Found</div>} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

But for me to get to all of the routes I need, would have to do a bunch of those `.map()`, which seems counter-productive. There must be a simpler and proper way to get this done. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you need to create all these routes. You could just use three by using URL parameters:

```js
const App = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/:item/about" component={<AboutItemComponent/>}/>
              <Route path="/:item/faq" component={<FaqItemComponent/>}/>
              <Route exact path="/:item" component={<ItemComponent/>}/>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

There is an example on the React Router site showing this too - https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params

As you can see in their example, those components that get rendered can then access the URL parameter and render the correct information for that item.

If you do have a more complex route structure than this you can start looking at their [Route Config example](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/route-config) and the [`react-router-config`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-config) module they have.

However, for the example routes you gave I would keep it simple and just use URL parameters.

Comment: Initially I did think of doing as your example, but I do not want anything to be accepted, only whatever is in my item array. Anything else should do a 404. The route config example may be more of what I'm looking for. Will give that a try shortly.

Comment: One way you could handle that is by accessing the URL parameter and rendering 404 content instead.

In `FaqItemComponent`, for example, you might get the URL parameter and it might be something completely different to what you expected. You could then just show your 404 content (possibly imported as a separate component).

The benefit of this is you keep the wrong URL in the address bar. It also works well when you may need to call an API first to verify if something exists.

You can see Google does this if you go to a URL like https://google.com/blah

Answer (score -1):

## Issue

The issue is that within the `Switch` component the ***first*** matching `Route` or `Redirect` is what is returned. In each set of routes that is mapped the `"/:item"` route path is listed prior to the more specific `"/:item/about"` and `"/:item/faq"` paths. This means the less specific path is matched and returned since it is encountered first.

The `component` prop also takes a reference to a React component, not JSX. `component={<Component />}` isn't valid.

## Solution

Switch up the order of the route paths so the more specific paths are listed before any less specific paths. Render the components on the `component` prop like `component={Component}`.

Example:

```
const items = [
  { id: 1, name: 'item1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'item2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'item3' },
  { id: 4, name: 'item4' }
];

const NotFound = () => <div>Not Found</div>;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        {items.map(({ name }) => (
          <React.Fragment key={name}>
            <Route path={`/${name}/about`} component={AboutItemComponent} />
            <Route path={`/${name}/faq`} component={FaqItemComponent} />
            <Route path={`/${name}`} component={ItemComponent} />
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Instead of mapping each element of `items` to the same set of routes you can optimize your routes to take a dynamic path segment and only render a single set of routes.

Example:

```
const NotFound = () => <div>Not Found</div>;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/:item/about" component={AboutItemComponent} />
        <Route path="/:item/faq" component={FaqItemComponent} />
        <Route path="/:item" component={ItemComponent} />
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

To limit the `item` route path parameter you can specify a regular expression to match only those names in the `items` array. See [route path](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/path-string-string) and [`path-to-regexp@^1.7.0`](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0) for more details.

Example:

```
const items = [
  { id: 1, name: 'item1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'item2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'item3' },
  { id: 4, name: 'item4' }
];

const NotFound = () => <div>Not Found</div>;

// build a path segment that looks like `:item(item1|item2|item3|item4)` *
const item = `:item(${items.map(({ name }) => name).join("|")})`;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={`/${item}/about`} component={AboutItemComponent} />
        <Route path={`/${item}/faq`} component={FaqItemComponent} />
        <Route path={`/${item}`} component={ItemComponent} />
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit create-multiple-routes-and-nested-routes-from-array]

**** Note:** I've assigned the path parameter `item`, but this isn't strictly required to specific route matching, for example paths works just as well as `path="/(item1|item2|item3|item4)"` and `path="/(item1|item2|item3|item4)/about"`. The `item` route path parameter is only if you want/need to access it in the routed component, e.g. `const { item } = useParams();`.*